# Not able to see Grafana Annotations

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am adding attonations to my grafana dashboard via the API `api/annotations`
with the request body:

```
{
 "time": 167419909,
 "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
 "text" : "My annotations"
}
```

As a response, I am getting `200 OK` with response body:

```
{
 "id": 24,
 "message": "Annotation Added"
}
```

Setting wise I have done the following:

1. In my dashboard setting I went to Annotations -> "+New Query"
2. Entered the name of annotation as "Events", datasource as --Grafana--
3. Ticked the Enabled Checkbox and Unticked the disabled Checkbox
4. Show In: All Panels
5. Query Type: Annotations and Alerts
6. Filter By: Tags
7. Max Limit: 100
8. Many Any: Toggled On
9. Tags: tag1,tag2,etc

But I still dont see any annotation on my graphs.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 days on the issue, finally found the problem :)

The timestamp in the request body has to be in `millisecond` and not in `seconds`.
Once I used the `millisecond` timestamp, the annotation appeared on the dashboard.

The strange thing is the response though. If timestamp in second is not acceptable, Grafana should not respond with a 200. A simple warning could have saved so much time.